# Where is the Trinity in the Climbing Trees?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I am wandering around the Climbing Trees, because the walkthrough I am following says that there is a Trinity in this area, which I really want to get.

Problem is, the Trinity marks are usually pretty tiny, and there is so much green and sameness in this area that I have really no idea where it is.

Where is the Trinity mark? What is it near?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this guide, which has pictures. http://www.supercheats.com/guides/kingdom-hearts/trinity-marks/

The blue trinity is at:
"Deep Jungle: Climbing Trees, right before the entrance to the Tree House"

Comment: I am looking for the Blue Trinity, actually. Also, could you edit the pertinent part of that link into your answer, to avoid link rot?

Comment: If I understand correctly, done. At this vintage I'd expect the link to be fairly stable, but point taken. FYI that the green trinity at "Treetop" is considered even harder to see.

Comment: by "entrance to the tree, do you mean the Tree House?" And yeah, that is what I meant by "avoiding link rot". :) Thanks for editing! :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Edited - third times a charm.